# Inserting and selecting from a table with a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm currently having issues with an objective for an online class I am taking. The objective is below this, The code I'm using along with the error I'm receiving will be below that.

Use a variable to write a procedure called "AddNewAlbum." This procedure takes at least two parameters - NameOfArtist and AlbumName. The procedure will:

1.Lookup ArtistID from the Artist table, where artist name is NameOfArtist

2.Insert a new row into Albums, using the ArtistID found in step #1 and the AlbumName parameter

For now it is safe to assume the artist exists before you run this procedure (meaning if you CALL AddNewAlbum ('Bob Dylan', 'Street Legal'); then "Bob Dylan" already exists in the Artist table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewAlbum (
NameOfArtist varcahr(50),
AlbumName varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
SELECT ArtistID, ArtistName FROM Artists
WHERE ArtistName = 'NameOfArtist';

INSERT INTO Albums (Title)
VALUES (AlbumName);
END;
//

CALL AddNewAlbum (
"Bob Dylan",
"Street Legal"
);
//
```

ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ArtistID' doesn't have a default value

^ Is the error I receive. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I tried taking the quotations around WHERE ArtistName = 'NameOfArtist';
but this did not work.

I'd like to add that it is pulling the Artists name and the ArtistID but is not adding the new row to Albums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement on this,

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewAlbum 
(
    @NameOfArtist varchar(50),
    @AlbumName varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Albums (ID, Title)
    SELECT  ArtistID, @AlbumName AS Title
    FROM    Artists
    WHERE   ArtistName = @NameOfArtist;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: With some tweaking to my Albums table I got it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code. There is spelling mistake in it. The spelling of `varchar` is wrong for NameOfArtist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewAlbum (
NameOfArtist varcahr(50),
AlbumName varchar(50)
)
```

Please try and correct it.

Comment: Thank for that! I actually caught it while trying to tweak the code but just forgot to edit it here.